# How to find the lock owner thread in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, scenekit, deadlock, arkit

Is there any way to find which thread causing an `__ulock_wait` for other in iOS? 
The Camera view in my AR App hangs during AR session. Seems that the rendering thread is blocked, causing main thread blocked.
Thank you in advanced
[image]

Comment: Is this bug reproduces each time, on under specific conditions? Do you have any threads you manage by yourself?

Comment: Hi, it happens when I move my phone quickly during AR session. I don't manage any thread.